# Can one use a slash / in as a variable and then fetch it with $_GET

Tags: php, variables, get

Is there a problem with passing a slash in a variable like this:

```
example.com?variables=big/dash&others=slow/march
```

I am using it to pass variables to a PHP file to give the locations of the CSS files it then needs to include in the head section. Is this alright or should I construct the variables with another delimiter and then turn than into a slash once on the PHP page.

Best,

Comment: What holds you from trying?

Comment: you can use urlencode()

Comment: Tested it locally and there is nothing wrong with having slashes in the GET. The slashes will be a part of the variable.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Fear and indecision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything from the ? will be interpreted as query string and hence that should be OK.

You should [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can get these parameters with `$_GET` but I think its better to send only an abstract for those files and make sure you white list it:

example:

> ?variables=big&others=slow

And then create an array:

```
$locations = array('big' => 'big/dash&others', 'slow' => 'slow/march');
//check 
if(array_key_exists($_GET['key'], $locations)){
//include $locations[$_GET['key']);
}
```